# Extending properties generated using @synthesize in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have an @property declared like this:

```
@property (readwrite,retain) NSObject *someObject;
```

And I synthesize it like this:

```
@synthesize someObject = _someObject;
```

This generates getters/setters for me. Also, according to the docs, the setter will have built in thread safety code.

Now, suppose I want to add some code to the setSomeObject: method. Is there any way that I can extend the existing on from @synthesize? I want to be able to reuse the the thread safety code that it autogenerates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `@synthesize` does is equivalent to:

```
-(void)setSomeObject:(NSObject *)anObject {
    [anObject retain];
    [someObject release];
    someObject = anObject;
}
```

or

```
-(void)setSomeObject:(NSObject *)anObject {
    if(someObject != anObject) {
        [someObject release];
        someObject = [anObject retain];
    }
}
```

so you can use this code and extend the method.

However, as you said, this code might not be thread-safe.

For thread safety, you might want to take a look at [`NSLock`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nslock_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or `@synchronized` (thanks to [unwesen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41081/unwesen) for pointing this out).

Comment: @synchronized is probably a better option than NSLock - simpler at any rate.

Comment: Don't forget the KVO calls:
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"someObject"];
    ...
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"someObject"];

Comment: Adding the KVO calls aren't necessary unless you've disabled automatic KVO support by implementing +automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:. The generation of KVO calls is not part of @synthesize

Comment: This answer is actually not correct. The @property as declared is atomic, which means it uses a lock internally, though whether it uses a per-property lock or the equivalent of @synchronized(self) is undocumented.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a synthesized "private" property, (put this in your `.m` file)

```
@interface ClassName ()

// Declared properties in order to use compiler-generated getters and setters
@property (nonatomic, strong <or whatever>) NSObject *privateSomeObject;

@end
```

and then manually define a getter and setter in the "public" part of `ClassName` (`.h` and `@implementation` part) like this,

```
- (void) setSomeObject:(NSObject *)someObject {
  self.privateSomeObject = someObject;
  // ... Additional custom code ...
}

- (NSArray *) someObject {
  return self.privateSomeObject;
}
```

You can now access the `someObject` "property" as usual, e.g. `object.someObject`. You also get the advantage of automatically generated `retain`/`release`/`copy`, compatibility with ARC and almost lose no thread-safety.