# Responding to setters

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the best way to respond to data changes when property setters are called. For example, if I have a property called `data`, how can I react when `[object setData:newData]` is called and still use the synthesised setter. Instinctively, I would override the synthesised setter like so:

```
- (void)setData:(DataObject *)newData {
    // defer to synthesised setter
    [super setData:newData];

    // react to new data
    ...
}
```

...but of course this doesn't make sense - I can't use `super` like this. So what is the best way to handle this situation? Should I be using KVO? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, depending on how much control you want. One way to do it is to observe your own property:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"data" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object == self && [path isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        //handle change here
    } else [super observeValueForKeyPath:path ofObject:object change:change context:context];
}
```

Make sure you remove yourself as an observer in your dealloc or finalize method, if not before.

Another way would be to override `-didChangeValueForKey:`. However, this method may not be called if there are no observers on the object.

```
- (void)didChangeValueForKey:(NSString *)key {
    [super didChangeValueForKey:key];
    if([key isEqualToString:@"data"]) {
        //handle change here
    }
}
```

Comment: Overriding `-didChangeValueForKey:` is not be recommended. If you're using automatic KVO notifications (which most classes do), that method won't be called until an observer has been added.

Comment: @Mike: That's why its only the second option.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Mike. @ughoavgfhw, maybe you can edit that caveat into your answer.

Comment: Are the KVO mechanisms built into the getters and setters provided by `@synthesize`? I.e. if I were to write my own getter and simply release and retain, would I potentially be breaking KVO?

Comment: As far as I can tell, synthesized properties only generate their own notifications code if `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` returns `NO`. So if you want to write your own *setter* method (I assume that's what you mean), then it's fine simply to release and retain.

Comment: Custom setters are no problem for KVO. KVO works by creating a dynamic subclass of your object at *runtime*. That subclass wraps your setters with calls to willSetValueForKey:/didSetValueForKey:.

That's why it doesn't usually get called; because the default synthesised accessors don't include those calls.

Answer (score 2):

@synthesize creates default accessors for easy use. In case some special action is needed then it is always possible to write own accessors instead of using @synthesize. The setter and getter are not inherited from base class, they are created by the @synthesize directive. So you don't need to (neither you can) call super setData: (unless you really have created super class that support that).

Just ensure that you are managing memory correctly. [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) contains examples on how to manage memory for different types of memory policy (retain or assign or copy).

Comment: I'm trying to find out if there's a way I can have it both ways: respond to the change _and_ keep the implementation provided by `@synthesize`. Overriding the accessor and adding the memory management manually feels wrong. Is there perhaps a cleaner way to respond to property changes?

Comment: It's actually not wrong, neither something that is not-recommended. Personally I prefer that. Obviously there might be other better ways. let's check what other people suggest.

Comment: For KVO, please check http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Concepts/AutoVsManual.html. It says "You can control automatic observer notifications for properties of your subclass by implementing the class method automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:.", Though I have not tested that myself. So can't tell how difficult it will be to implement.

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301308/1071136).

You can define a synthesized "private" property, (put this in your `.m` file)

```
@interface ClassName ()

// Declared properties in order to use compiler-generated getters and setters
@property (nonatomic, strong <or whatever>) NSObject *privateSomeObject;

@end
```

and then manually define a getter and setter in the "public" part of `ClassName` (`.h` and `@implementation` part) like this,

```
- (void) setSomeObject:(NSObject *)someObject {
  self.privateSomeObject = someObject;
  // ... Additional custom code ...
}

- (NSArray *) someObject {
  return self.privateSomeObject;
}
```

You can now access the `someObject` "property" as usual, e.g. `object.someObject`. You also get the advantage of automatically generated `retain`/`release`/`copy`, compatibility with ARC and almost lose no thread-safety.